# Need to upgrade and relocate Subversion repo - catch 22?

Tags: svn, version-control

I came across an interesting Catch 22 today trying to recover an old Subversion repo and working copies.

I initially moved and upgraded the repo, then went to upgrade the working copy and point it at the newly moved repo.

```
$ svn upgrade
svn: E180001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///OLD/REPO/PATH'
svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///OLD/REPO/PATH'
```

So, upgrade fails because the repo is pointed to the wrong place. No problem, I'll repoint the working copy at the new repo path:

```
$ svn switch --relocate file:///OLD/REPO/PATH file:///NEW/REPO/PATH .
svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command
svn: E155036: Working copy '/WORKING/COPY/PATH' is too old (format 10, created by Subversion 1.6)
```

And that's a perfect Catch 22 - can't upgrade because the repo path is wrong, can't fix the repo path because you haven't upgraded.

Comment: Haha, not bad! 

I was actually moving the repo from Ubuntu to my Mac, so I would have ended up with a weird one file /home/USERNAME/ hierarchy, but this would totally have worked. I could have easily deleted the symbolic link after svn upgrade too.

Upvote for creativity :)

Comment: On Windows you can create a temporary entry in the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file to map the old url to the current repository which will allow you to upgrade and then finally relocate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to downgrade the subversion client, or install the old binary in a different directory and temporarily prepend that location to your path. This will allow you to relocate the repository first then you can switch to the new client and upgrade it.

Comment: Good point. I found getting older clients on Mac difficult, but this is probably the correct way to go about it.

Comment: Shouldn't be too difficult - try here: http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#osx . I found it harder getting hold of 1.7 binaries than 1.6

Comment: Thanks! BTW, for 1.7 binaries, I used Macports: http://www.macports.org/ and found it pretty smooth. I know not everyone likes macports though :)

Answer (score 4):

My working copy suggested that I should do a "svn upgrade". After doing this, I cannot connect to my local repository with URL "file:///...". All alternatives to that did not work, except the one I comment out in the following lines.

I have solved this issue by doing this steps:

1. Creating a new working copy from the same repository "file:///...": "svn checkout file:///... new-wc".
2. Applying the current changes from my old working copy (using "rsync -a old-wc/ new-wc/").
3. Commiting new changes to the repository.
4. Delete all working copy ("rm -rf old-wc").
5. Replacing the "working" ;-) working copy: "mv new-wc old-wc".

That's worked for me. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting the answer I came up with in case it helps someone. It's not ideal though, so I'm very interested to see if someone else has a better solution.

I grepped the files in the working copy to see where /OLD/REPO/PATH was mentioned; the only place was in the ".svn/entries" file in every folder.

So, I figured I'd make my own "svn switch --relocate", by just running a quick bash script to replace that path in each entries file:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in `sudo find . -name "entries"`
do
   sudo perl -pi -e 's/OLD\/REPO\/PATH/NEW\/REPO\/PATH/g' "$f"
done
```

Anyone know a simpler way around this, or of any disadvantages to manually changing the repo path in the "entries" files?

Comment: if there is a "@" in the repo path, it has to be escaped too: "\@".